# How can achive in rxjs that generate streams with random incrementing numbers and if one this reach a certian amount stop all streams

Tags: rxjs

I have to make a like a "car racing" app with rxjs.
like this:

```
car1: 100---200---400---550---780---820-1000
car2: 100---300-450-520-600--750--810----1000
```

Its just an example not precise at all.The numbers are randoms and if they reach 1000 need the stop all streams and write out which car is the winner.I will with this numbers later modify css property then i could to move this "cars" on screen. My question is:
With which rxjs operator could i achieve this?

Comment: Create a tick generator(interval or smth another). Then from this generator begin two flow branches that will randomly decide react to tick or not. And if yes, then add to current number some random value

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this:

I just add 50-150 randomly to each car every 50ms, printing the race and final winner to the console.

```ts
timer(0,50).pipe(
  map(_ => ({
    car1: Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50),
    car2: Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50)
  })),
  scan(
    (acc, v) => ({
      car1: acc.car1 + v.car1, 
      car2: acc.car2 + v.car2
    }), 
    { car1: 0, car2: 0 }
  ),
  takeWhile(({car1, car2}) => car1 < 10000 && car2 < 10000, true)
).subscribe(v => {
  console.log(v)

  if(v.car1 >= 10000){
    console.log("Car 1 won!!!");
  }else if(v.car2 >= 10000){
    console.log("Car 2 won!!!");
  }

});
```

---

Depending on how you want to structure thing. You can set up separate subscriptions for the race and for the final result. Here I multicast the source (`shareReplay`) but still just print to the console.

Depending on how you design this, this could create a nicer separation of concerns.

```ts
const race$ = timer(0,50).pipe(
  map(_ => ({
    car1: Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50),
    car2: Math.floor(Math.random() * (150 - 50) + 50)
  })),
  scan(
    (acc, v) => ({
      car1: acc.car1 + v.car1, 
      car2: acc.car2 + v.car2
    }), 
    { car1: 0, car2: 0 }
  ),
  takeWhile(({car1, car2}) => car1 < 10000 && car2 < 10000, true),
  shareReplay(1)
);

// Race Updates print to the console
race$.subscribe(console.log);

// Final Winner print to the console
race$.pipe(
  last(),
  map(({car1, car2}) => car1 > car2 ? "Car 1" : "Car 2")
).subscribe(winner => console.log(`${winner} won the race!`));
```